# XSL-FO background image corrupting generated pdf

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I am generating a PDF from this xsl document below. I am trying to add a background image to cover the entire generated pdf but it keeps corrupting the pdf on generation when I include the `<fo: block-container>` on line 12. Is there another way I can generate a background image or is there something I am doing incorrect here?

I also attempted to include the background image using an `<fo:external-graphic>` which did display the image but left a border at the top (which I presume is the region-before). But this only works with a hosted image url and not with a locally stored image which isn't an issue but I found a bit strange.

`<fo:block text-align="center" display-align="before">
    <fo:external-graphic top="-20mm" bottom="-20mm" content-width="210mm" height="150mm" src="url()">
    </fo:external-graphic>
</fo:block>`

`

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page" page-height="150mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="10mm" margin-bottom="10mm" margin-left="12mm" margin-right="12mm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm" />
                <!-- <fo:region-before extent="20mm" /> -->
                <!-- <fo:region-after extent="20mm" /> -->
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">
            <fo:flow flow-name='xsl-region-body' font-size="20pt">
                <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="-20mm" bottom="-20mm" width="210mm" height="150mm" background-image="/Users/myname/Downloads/background.png">
                    <fo:block/>
                </fo:block-container>                   
                <xsl:apply-templates select="certificate" />
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="certificate">
    <fo:block text-align="center">
        <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
        <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
        <xsl:variable name="bgImg" select="/images/background.png"/>



        <fo:block font-size="30pt" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="first_title" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="14pt" padding-before="3mm" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="student_name" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="school_name" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="20pt" padding-before="3mm" padding-after="5mm" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="second_title" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="level_passed" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="third_title" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="14pt" padding-before="8mm" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="fourth_title" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="teacher_name" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="date" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="student_name">
    <fo:block space-before="10mm" space-before.conditionality="retain">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="student_name" />
            <xsl:text>of</xsl:text>
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="school_name">
    <fo:block space-after="10mm" space-before="5pt" space-after.conditionality="retain">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="school_name" />
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="level_passed">
    <fo:block space-before="10mm" space-before.conditionality="retain">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="level_passed" />
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="teacher_name">
    <fo:block space-before="5pt">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="teacher_name" />
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="date">
    <fo:block space-before="5pt">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="date" />
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

`

Comment: fo:region-body can have @background-image property. Do you have already try it?

Comment: @tmakita I did, still causes the PDF to corrupt when generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by adding the `<fo:block-container>` around the content I was pulling in for student-name and school-name etc. Full code below

`

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page" page-height="211mm" page-width="338mm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="3cm" margin-right="3cm">
                                <fo:region-body/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">
            <fo:flow flow-name='xsl-region-body' font-size="20pt" letter-spacing="0.05pt">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="certificate" />
            </fo:flow>
             </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="certificate">


    <xsl:variable name="imageHref"><xsl:value-of select="background"/></xsl:variable>

      <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute"
        top="-2cm" left="-3cm" width="338mm" height="211mm"
        background-image="{$imageHref}">

        <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
        <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
        <xsl:variable name="bgImg" select="/images/background.png"/>

        <fo:block font-size="45pt" text-align="center" color="#000000" padding-top="4cm" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
             This <fo:inline font-family="serif" font-size="50pt" font-weight="bold" font-style="italic"><xsl:value-of select="first_title" /></fo:inline> honors
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="20pt" padding-top="5mm" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="student-name" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="20pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="school-name" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block padding-top="1cm" font-size="35pt" padding-before="3mm" padding-after="5mm" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            for <fo:inline font-family="serif" font-size="40pt" font-weight="bold" font-style="italic"><xsl:value-of select="second_title" /></fo:inline> the
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="20pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="dropdown" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="20pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="additional-info" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block padding-top="1.5cm" font-size="20pt" padding-bottom="5mm" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="fourth_title" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-size="20pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="teacher-name" />
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block padding-bottom="1cm"  font-size="20pt" font-weight="lighter" text-align="center" color="#000000" font-family=" Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
            <xsl:value-of select="date" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="student-name">
    <fo:block space-before="10mm" space-before.conditionality="retain">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="student_name" />
            <xsl:text>of</xsl:text>
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="school-name">
    <fo:block space-before="5pt" space-after.conditionality="retain">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="school_name" />
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dropdown">
    <fo:block space-before="10mm" space-before.conditionality="retain">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="level_passed" />
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="teacher-name">
    <fo:block space-before="5pt">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="teacher_name" />
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="date">
    <fo:block space-before="5pt">
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="date" />
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

`